# HLS player with mooTools 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, mootools, video.js, http-live-streaming, hls.js

We've bene hired to do some work on a site that uses mooTools 1.4.5 as its javascript framework.

For the sake of this project we need to be able to play HLS video streams on that site. We tried to use videojs 7.0.3 + videojs-contrib-hls 5.14 as we had good experience with this player, but it looks like it conflicts with mooTools, maybe around Function.prototype.bind as suggested by a thread on github (see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3097 )

I'm attaching a screencapture from the console:[Screen capture from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC5Qj.jpg)

Could anybody advice how to solve the problem without breaking either the player or mooTools?

Do you know of any HLS player that will definitely work with mooTools 1.4.5 and not require JQuery?

Thanks for any help

Comment: 7.0.3 already includes hls tech.

Comment: True - we just noticed. But thanks for pointing out. Any suggestion regarding the problem we are having?

Comment: Did you try it without videojs-contrib-hls just only with built-in hls feature?

Comment: Yes I did - but i get the same error

Comment: Then I have only one idea - return back overrided bind method. Before loading mooTools, do `nativeBind = Function.prototype.bind;` and immediately when script loaded return it back like `Function.prototype.bind = nativeBind;`. Then load videojs. You will see if it will break something.. That mooTools goes against all prooved conventions..

Comment: not a bad idea per se, but both the videojs object and several mooTools objects are being constantly called inside the page. I don't know how could we keep switching back and forth between the two versions? Maybe we could reassign the original .bind ONLY to the prototype of the object that causes the problem?

Comment: I think that all of this is only mitigating of damage done by mooTools and will never lead to nice solution and sustainabilty. Everytime you add some code or plugin, you will be possibly solving this xxxx. I think that today is no reason for using frameworks like jQuery or mooTools, but atleast jQuery does not break Javascript language.. So my advice: remove mooTools. In the end it will be maybe fastest and most effecient solution you can do..

Comment: Or look at [this](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2473). Maybe different version of mooTools will resolve it..

Comment: HI Bigless, this links you found are actually quite helpful. I'm tempted by the change of version of mooTools - only problem is that Social Engine comes out of the box with the version with backward compatibility layer... it's very likely that if i switch to the no compatib version the player will work - but I risk to break a lot of other third parties modules... I'm think to perhaps link the no compat version only on the pages where our code goes and to put it below the official one - maybe the no compatibility will overwrite the other. FIngers crossed!!!